# Dimension of kernel of closure of an unbounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space.

$$T:D \rightarrow H$$ 
be a densely defined  unbounded operator.  Suppose $\dim \ker T < \infty$. Let $\bar{T}$ be its [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator), supposing its existence.

> Is it true that $\dim \ker \bar{T}= \dim \ker T$?